# Add Drum Track to MP3

Tags: windows, mp3, audio-editing

I'm looking for something to add a drum track to an MP3.

- Windows 10
- Create a full (not overly simplified) drum track
- Add drum track to an existing MP3
- Free would be nice as this is just a one-time project
- Existing drum samples would be nice (but can d/l from Internet)

Comment: I've never used one these but please look at free or open source "alternatives" at this link: https://alternativepedia.com/fl-studio/

Comment: Don't know if it can do what you want but [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/about/screenshots) is a free and Open Source audio editor

Comment: Audacity doesn't have drum samples as far as I know. And adding some existing samples would be hard.

Comment: I just downloaded [LMMS](https://lmms.io/). Looks pretty intimidating. Will update with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a drum track with one of the many online drum machines, download it, and use [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to add it to the mp3.

One of my favorite drum machines is [Drumbot](https://www.drumbot.com/projects/drumbot/).

Drumbot allows you to download your track as a .wav file, and the site doesn't say anything about licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said a "full (not overly simplified)" drum track, I'll assume you don't want to just use loops. Disclaimer: I'm a musician and have an audio production background. That said, I would use:
 - [Reaper: a free-to-try full-fledged DAW.](https://www.reaper.fm) with a plug-in like [EZdrummer](https://www.toontrack.com/product/ezdrummer-2/) or...
 - [Propellerheads REASON](https://www.propellerheads.se/en/reason) (30 day trial)

Of the two, Reason is more intuitive and easy to use IHO. All of this really depends on how much time and effort you are looking to invest, but you can make professional sounding drum tracks quite easily with Reason.